# A Joomla Quandry

Tags: joomla

I've been trying to figure this one out but im stumped, is it possible to display all articles within a category? I mean im using a category list menu type and what i want is when u visit a specific category it outputs all the articles 'content' relating to said category onto the page rather than just displaying the links to each article. I could do some OOP and make the request myself as a last resort but id rather try and accomplish the task within the framework.

Comment: You're going to hate this answer (which is why I'm leaving it as a comment), but unless you find a plugin that perfectly fits your requirements, I find the only way to get Joomla to do exactly what you want is to meander through the spaghetti code that was written by the people who put it together. Another option is to not use Joomla and move to something like CodeIgniter or Kohana. Hope this was of some marginal help, but I fully expect it not to have been. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with template overrides.

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

In the example given they use an article, but you can use a category or anything else.

Comment: much obliged thanx ill give it a go